# Two PCRE regular expressions

Tags: regex, pcre

I need to turn this format `[url]3a7cHPy04s8[/youtube]`

Into: `[media=youtube]3a7cHPy04s8[/media]​`

and this format `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h_JfHLs2Nc4`

Into: `[media=youtube]h_JfHLs2Nc4[/media]​`

They will be used in this tool
https://xenforo.com/community/resources/post-content-find-replace.1549/

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is the domain a variable?

Comment: No, I don't think so

Answer (score 1):

Match:

```
~\[url\](\w+)\[/youtube\]~
```

Or:

```
~https?://(?:www\.)?youtube\.com/watch\?\S*?v=(\w+)\S*~
```

And replace with:

```
[media=youtube]\1[/media]​
```

Comment: Two replacements it is!

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex replacement:

```
(?|\Q[url]\E([\w-]+)\Q[/youtube]\E|https?:\Q//\E(?:youtu\.be\/|(?:www\.)?\Qyoutube.com/watch?v=\E)([\w-]+))
```

To replace to:

```
[media=youtube]\1[/media]​
```

As a bonus just for you, it also works with `http://youtu.be/(id)`!
See a [regex demo here](http://regex101.com/r/hF9uR5/2).

Explained:

```
/(?| # Branch Reset: Use persistent group ordering
  \Q[url]\E
  # Literal "[url]"
  ([\w-]+)
  # Stuff that can be within a video ID
  \Q[/youtube]\E
  # Closing tag
| # "or" Alternation, reset group ordering
  https?:\Q//\E
  # http(s)://
  (?:
    youtu\.be\/
  | # youtu.be or (www.)youtube.com/watch?v=
    (?:www\.)?\Qyoutube.com/watch?v=\E
  )
  ([\w-]+)
  # Stuff that can be within a video ID
)/gx
```

Comment: Have my +1 for 2-upping me ;) FYI: I updated the RegEx demo to include the substitution in case OP isn't used to seeing a replacement with capture groups.

Comment: @Sam thanks :) will upvote your answer as well in 18 minutes or when I get home, depending on which comes first, considering I have to head to a function and am out of votes for this Stack Overflow day ;)